# R and Web Scraping with looping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping a website with `urls http://example.com/post/X` , where **X is a number stating from 1:5000**
I can scrape using `rvest` using this code:

```
website <- html("http://www.example.com/post/1")

Name <- website%>% 
  html_node("body > div > div.row-fluid > div > div.DrFullDetails > div.MainDetails > div.Description > h1") %>%
  html_text()

Speciality <- website %>% 
  html_node("body > div > div.row-fluid > div > div.DrFullDetails > div.MainDetails > div.Description > p.JobTitle") %>%
  html_text()
```

I need the code to grab all the pages from the website and put the scraped data in a table with every page in a new row.
Please Help

Comment: Please Show your effort first.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your code for scraping a single page in an `lapply`, and then use `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package to combine the information from each page.

This is hard to test without an actual example, but try something like this:

```
library(rvest)
library(data.table)

scrapeDomain <- function(baseURL="http://www.domain.com/post", index=1:10) {

  scrape1 <- lapply(index, function(n) {

    website <- paste(baseURL, n, sep="/") %>%
      html()

    name <- website %>% 
      html_node("body > div > div.row-fluid > div > div.DrFullDetails > div.MainDetails > div.Description > h1") %>%
      html_text()

    speciality <- website %>% 
      html_node("body > div > div.row-fluid > div > div.DrFullDetails > div.MainDetails > div.Description > p.JobTitle") %>%
      html_text()

    data.table(website=website, name=name, specialty=specialty)

  } )

  rbindlist(scrape1)

}

scrapeDomain()
```